# How to post a UI message from a worker thread in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, multithreading, message

I'm writing a simple winforms app in C#. I create a worker thread and I want the main window to respond to the tread finishing its work--just change some text in a text field, testField.Text = "Ready". I tried events and callbacks, but they all execute in the context of the calling thread and you can't do UI from a worker thread.

I know how to do it in C/C++: call PostMessage from the worker thread. I assume I could just call Windows API from C#, but isn't there a more .NET specific solution?

Comment: Control.BeginInvoke() is the *exact* equivalent to PostMessage().  With the added advantage that you can pick the target method and pass it any arguments you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event callback from the completed thread, use the `InvokeRequired` pattern, as demonstrated by the various answers to this SO post demonstrate.

[C#: Automating the InvokeRequired code pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/c-automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern)

Another option would be to use the `BackgroundWorker` component to run your thread.  The `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler executes in the context of the thread that started the worker.

Answer (score 1):

i normally do something like this

```
void eh(Object sender,
EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      this.Invoke(new EventHandler(this.eh, new object[] { sender,e });
       return;
    }  
    //do normal updates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Control.Invoke() or Form.Invoke() method executes the delegate you provide on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Invoke function of the form. The function will be run on the UI thread.

EX :

```
...
MethodInvoker meth = new MethodInvoker(FunctionA);
form.Invoke(meth);
....

void FunctionA()
{
   testField.Text = "Ready". 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using C# MethodInvoker.Invoke() for a GUI app... is this good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782274/using-c-methodinvoker-invoke-for-a-gui-app-is-this-good/782289#782289)