# Function in multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two threads t1 and t2. I get information in t1 and based on it I want to call function in t2 which will work in t2.
How can I do it?

## Edit:

t2 is thread with c# form. t1 is working in a loop and it gets information that t2 should call function. I think that shared objects won't work, because t2 doesn't work in a loop, so I can't check if some object has changed.

Comment: interesting. and the question is ?

Comment: create a new object inheriting said object and add event handling while maintaining the lock pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share the object between both threads (for example a member of a class where both threads run) and access it using the `lock` pattern:

```
object _someobject; // as a member for example

...

lock (_someobject)
{
// manipulate the object
}
```

This ensures object consistency with avoiding both threads interacting with the shared object at the same time.

Another option would be to use a [MethodInvoker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782274/using-c-methodinvoker-invoke-for-a-gui-app-is-this-good) if one of the threads is a GUI thread for example.

Comment: You could use a shared/static variable that both threads can touch using a lock.

Comment: Yes, the object could also be static, but then take care, it is global. Still an option if you think about system or application settings for example.

Comment: Ok, MethodInvoker helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the proper way would be to use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) or [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx). You call it on t1, and it gets executed on t2. You need to have a reference to some control running in t2, e.g., the form itself.

You can include the data into the closure, which you invoke in t2.

Answer (score 0):

I envision using a volatile variable to store the information found by t1 while t2 loops using an exception until the desired informaiton is found.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: volatile would be ok for fields only, not for objects in general.

Comment: Point. A mention of objets would have my useful on my part. "Fools Despise Wisdom, Instruction, and Correction"

Answer (score 0):

You would use Monitor.Wait and Pulse. They will share a locking object and a signalling variable. The waiting thread would be blocked until signaled (pulsed by working thread).
e.g:

```
    bool _go;
lock (_locker)
            {
                while (!_go) Monitor.Wait(_locker);

            }
            CallFunc();
```

Working thread:

```
   // do work here
   DoWork();
   lock (_locker)
        {
            _go = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(_locker);
        }
```

Comment: The thread t2 where the function should be executed is a GUI thread. You cannot do long `Wait`s there.

Comment: You are correct, but he doesn't say actually say UI thread. I assumed they are a couple of worker threads. Anyway, it is fairly pointless trying to write code to solve a problem, where the problem isn't clear because the OP didn't post any code. Lesson learned. :-|

Comment: anyway, we are here to help, and in many cases answer requires some guesswork. With guessing, one cannot make a reliable solution.