# how to get path of the browsed file and to be written in its textbox in c#?

Tags: c#

my code is--

```
    protected void BrowseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newThread.Start();
    }


    void ThreadMethod()
    {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            BrowseTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName), dlg.FileName);
    }
```

please help......

Comment: You may find you need to `Invoke` the call to the `Text` property. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782274/using-c-sharp-methodinvoker-invoke-for-a-gui-app-is-this-good

Comment: i am unable to write the path of the browsed file into the browsetextbox

Comment: the code has no prblm except what is stated above

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you really need. I assume that you have a problem with updating a UI control from another thread.

```
void ThreadMethod()
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.ShowDialog();
    MethodInvoker invoker = delegate 
    {
        BrowseTextBox.Text = .... 
    };

    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(invoker);
    }
    else
    {
        invoker();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For WPF application you should change the code above. Here is the example:

```
Action invoker = delegate 
    {
        BrowseTextBox.Text = .... 
    };
Dispatcher.Invoke(invoker);
```

Comment: my code is creating a browse button and i used a thread to handle sta exception but i am unable to write the path of the browsed file into the browsetextbox

Comment: You must always update UI controls from the GUI thread.

I gave you an example how to do this for WinForm application. If you are building a WPF application, the updating controls will be slightly different.

Answer (score -1):

BrowseTextBox.Text = dlg.FileName

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. The OP's code related to doing this bit seems to be fine. I suspect it is a threading issue